# How to add n number of spaces at frontend

Tags: linux, shell

I have a text file : ABC.txt which contain below data

I want to to `n` number of spaces at the frontend of my text file on every line

```
A Apple a day keeps a doctor away 
B I like to play with Ball
C I have cat at my home
D My Dog name is bob
I want to display output on my screen with 10 spaces in a frontend and then my file data
```

**Expected output :**

```
  A Apple a day keeps a doctor away 
  B I like to play with Ball
  C I have cat at my home
  D My Dog name is bob
```

I have tried this but not working

**Command :**

```
prefix='          '
sed "s/^/$prefix/" ABC.txt
```

I want generic code so that incase I need to add much more spaces then my prefix should not be required to change

Like i want 20 spaces -> so i will pass  -> 20 as an input and my text will be formated with 20 spaces in frontend of my text file on every line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `perl`:

```
n=12
perl -spe '$_ = " " x $n . $_' -- -n="$n" < your-file
```

With `awk`:

```
n=12
awk -v n="$n" '
  BEGIN{indent = sprintf("%*s", n, "")}
  {print indent $0}' < your-file
```

With `zsh` and `sed`:

```
n=12
sed "s/^/${(l[$n])}/" < your-file
```

Where `l[n]` is the parameter expansion flag for left padding, here applied to no parameter at all.

With bash, zsh or ksh93, you can also do:

```
n=12
printf -v indent "%${n}s"
sed "s/^/$indent/" < your-file
```

With POSIX shells:

```
n=12
indent=$(printf "%${n}s")
sed "s/^/$indent/" < your-file
```

Answer (score 0):

This *should* work, though I'm not sure I understand what you meant when you said the similar sed command you mentioned didn't work; was it just that you weren't able to specify the number?

Here's one way you can:

```
#!/bin/bash
numspaces="$1"
prefix=''
for ((i=0;i<$numspaces;i++)) ; do 
    prefix="$prefix "
done
sed "s/^/$prefix/" ABC.txt
```

Save as "pad.sh", make it executable `chmod a+x pad.sh` and run `./pad.sh 19` to pad with 19 spaces.